# How can I plot several series as lines and one of them as area using ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to accomplish something that I used to do in Excel, I have several timeseries for the same time interval and would like to plot them as lines (easy enough using ggplot geom_line), but one of them should be plotted as an area plot.

Basically something like this:

[image: Desired]

Plase note that the series S_1 is plotted as area.

I have already tried adding geom_area() with aes values equal to the value of the area series:

```
ggplot(df.lines, aes(x=Index, y=Value, colour=Series)) + geom_line() + geom_area(aes(x=df.area$Index, y=df.area$S_1))
```

How could I acomplish something like this using ggplot2?

Comment: How about trying: `geom_area(data = df.area, aes(x=Index, y=S_1))`. Also what have you tried, and what was the result?

Comment: It just gave an error about `Series` object not found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Difficult to test with no dataset (can you provide one on the example, you can use `dput()`), but in `geom_area`, the selection should be made in the `data` argument.. like this for instance..

```
ggplot +
geom_area(data = df.area[df.area$Series == "S_1", ], aes(x=Index, y=Value)) 
  geom_line(data = df.lines, aes(x=Index, y=Value, colour=Series))
```

Comment: I think that in the `aes()` from `geom_area`, it should have `y=Value` instead of `Series`

Comment: Also, if you don't want to have the `geom_area` hide any lines or affect the color (if alpha is set to <1) you should put `geom_area` before `geom_line` and therefore call `data=df.lines` in in `geom_line`

Comment: @haboryme Right again!

Comment: Thanks to both of you, accepted answer and also the tip about the alpha < 1.

Comment: Just to comment on the solution, the fact that I changed the order of the `geom_line` and `geom_area` calls managed to acomplish the suggestions of @Haboryme